# compilation Linux in a Windows project

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, compilation

I have a project, I can compile only under Windows. How do I compile it for Linux? Creating a separate project in my Linux project and copying files from project to project all the time is inconvenient. How to solve?
p.s. In the project I have a division into #ifdef WIN32 and #ifdef linux, it remains only convenient to compile it for two platforms

Comment: we will need much more info on why you can only compile it on windows. What's so specific that another compiler can't compile it on a another operating system?

Comment: Visual Studio can compile _for_ Linux, but not _under_ Linux.

Comment: @MSalters 'google translate' made a mistake. Yes. I need to be able to compile my project for Windows and Linux in Visual Studio in a convenient way